# ExtJs button's menu contents not rendered until button is clicked

Tags: button, extjs, menu

I have a simple button with menu. There is a treepanel inside the menu.

Whenever user selects some node in tree, i update the container buttons text.

In treepanel's afterrender event i make a default node selection in the tree and this fire selection event and the button's text is updated.

However, when the button is rendered for the very first time, the treepanel inside the menu is not yet rendered.

How can i make menu & treepanel render silently (adding to dom but not shown to user until button is clicked) after button is rendered?

Actually there is a workaround which i hesitate to use:

```
btn.showMenu(); 
btn.hideMenu();
```

Any better ideas?

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/exGk3/

**Code:**

```
var selectedNodeIndex = 1;

var onItemSelect = function (selModel, node, index) {
    var treePanel = selModel.view.up();
    var btn = treePanel.up("button");
    btn.setText(node.data.text);
};

var afterTreeRender = function (t) {
    t.selModel.select(selectedNodeIndex);
}

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    menu: {
        items: {
            xtype: "treepanel",
            id: "tree",
            indent: false,
            width: 150,
            height: 200,
            rootVisible: false,
            root: {
                children: [{
                    text: "item 1",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "item 2",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "item 3",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            },
            listeners: {
                select: {
                    fn: onItemSelect
                },
                afterrender: {
                    fn: afterTreeRender
                }
            }
        },
        showSeparator: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do here is to pass along the text needed for the button. It seems that you already know which node to select in the tree, then you probably know which text corresponds to the selected index.

If that's somehow not possible or API is not changeable here is a way for you to set button text programmatically: 
**http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/XSn7X/3/**

The changes from what you have done are 2 fold:

1. Use `Ext.define` method to define your class with `initComponent` method.
   The `initComponet` method is a hook after the constructor to setup aditional properties. The key here is that the instance of the class exists at this point and `*this*` context references the class instance.
2. Use Ext.create to create an instance of your customized button component.

In the `initComponment` method you just traverse the tree looking for the data you need and set the button text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually i need more than just setting button's text. I need to access/manipulate tree's properties (tree.selModel for instance) when the time button is rendered. The problem is, tree is not rendered therefor not properly accessible at the time button has created. You need an extra btn.menuShow() to make tree rendered.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, tree properties are available when the button is created. You can move creation of the tree panel and the store inside the initComponent of the button. There you can set any tree config properties you wish. What specific property do you need to set?

Comment: tree.selModel.getSelection() returns an empty array before tree is rendered.

Comment: thats because nothing is physically selected. why do you need to wait for physical selection? you have the  selected node index you can get data from the store by the same index. Thats what i did for you in the fiddle.

Comment: well, even if I try to make a selection programatically (on added event of the tree) it still returns an empty array.